# Svg React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, svg

i'm trying to get a svg checkmark in react native but I don't understand why I get a different svg.
I'm wondering if the problem is related to the path of the svg because I think that the other part  can't do much with this

```
import React, {useEffect } from 'react'
import Animated, { Easing, useSharedValue, useAnimatedProps, withTiming, interpolateColor } from 'react-native-reanimated'
import Svg , {Path , Defs , ClipPath ,G } from 'react-native-svg'
import AniamtedStroke from './animated-stroke'
const MARGIN = 10
const vWidth = 64 + MARGIN
const vHeight = 64 + MARGIN
```

**const checkMarkPath =
'M15 31.1977C23.1081 36.4884 29.5946 43 29.5946 43C29.5946 43 37.5 25.5 69 1.5'**

```
const outlineBoxPath =
  'M24 0.5H40C48.5809 0.5 54.4147 2.18067 58.117 5.88299C61.8193 9.58532 63.5 15.4191 63.5 24V40C63.5 48.5809 61.8193 54.4147 58.117 58.117C54.4147 61.8193 48.5809 63.5 40 63.5H24C15.4191 63.5 9.58532 61.8193 5.88299 58.117C2.18067 54.4147 0.5 48.5809 0.5 40V24C0.5 15.4191 2.18067 9.58532 5.88299 5.88299C9.58532 2.18067 15.4191 0.5 24 0.5Z'

  const AnimatedPath = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Path)

interface Props{
    checked?: boolean
}

const AnimatedCheckbox =(props: Props) => {
    const {checked} =props
    const checkmarkColor='#000000'
    const highlightColor='#ff0000'
    const boxOutlineColor='#000000'

    const progress=useSharedValue(0)

    useEffect(()=>{
        progress.value=withTiming(checked ? 1 : 0,
            {
                duration: checked ? 300 : 100,
                easing: Easing.linear
            })
    },[checked])

    const animatedBoxProps = useAnimatedProps(
      () => ({
        stroke: interpolateColor(
          Easing.bezier(0.16, 1, 0.3, 1)(progress.value),
          [0, 1],
          [boxOutlineColor, highlightColor],
          'RGB'
        ),
        fill: interpolateColor(
          Easing.bezier(0.16, 1, 0.3, 1)(progress.value),
          [0, 1],
          ['#00000000', highlightColor],
          'RGB'
        )
      }),
      [highlightColor, boxOutlineColor]
    )
      
 return(
    <Svg viewBox={[-MARGIN, -MARGIN, vWidth + MARGIN, vHeight + MARGIN].join(' ')}>
      <Defs>
        <ClipPath id="clipPath">
          <Path
            fill="white"
            stroke="gray"
            strokeLinejoin="round"
            strokeLinecap="round"
            d={outlineBoxPath}
          />
        </ClipPath>
      </Defs>
      <AnimatedPath
        d={outlineBoxPath}
        strokeWidth={7}
        strokeLinejoin="round"
        strokeLinecap="round"
        animatedProps={animatedBoxProps}
      />

<G clipPath="url(#clipPath)">
      <AniamtedStroke progress={progress} d={checkMarkPath} stroke={checkmarkColor} strokeWidth={10} strokeLinejoin="round" strokeLinecap="round" strokeOpacity={checked || false ? 1 : 0 } />
   </G>
    </Svg>
 )
}

export default AnimatedCheckbox
```

ù

[this is the svg that I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQgWM.png)

[this is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHr1b.png)

Comment: From experience: I strongly recommend this website for creating SVG components in RN: https://transform.tools/svg-to-react-native

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is related to the styling. I [rendered the SVG within a codepen](https://codepen.io/JonathanSouthern/pen/dyzQWZG) and was able to replicate the image you want.

You're going to want the set `fill:none`, as the SVG your receiving is filling between the corners of the checkmark

```
{
 fill:none; 
 stroke:#2d2c2a;
}
```

Comment: Hi @fil_2020 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.